# What edition of Visual Studio 2008 for commercial projects

Tags: visual-studio

Friend of mine just established own coding company. They wanted create professional application written in .NET.

Now he on the stage buying software. We have discussed what VS version is absolutely minimum for this purposes.

There are lot of different version Professional / Team Suite / Team Developer ...
I wonder what you recommend?

Ideally: less (possible) cost but not short-sightedness? Would be possible base on only VS Professional Edition?

---

I forgot to add that friend's company is partially refunded by EU. So it would be better to him spend more money at start then pay for upgrade in future. So, looking rather for target solution.

We have looked at comparison matrix obviously. We couldn't find strong arguments for "Team" edition. Believe most of "Team" features can be  supplemented by 3rd parity tools (nUnit, Subversion, Resharper) what he used to use anyway...

If VS Professional would be selected - GDR will be the one think we noticed really missing in that approach.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely check out Microsoft [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/). For next to nothing Microsoft will provide a software startup with Visual Studio, SQL Server, and other dev tools. I would also say that the edition doesn't matter as much as what comes with it. Look at the feature matrices of the various VS packages and figure out what you need. You can always upgrade later. I've done a lot of contract work with VS Express and there are no licensing restrictions on what you do with the software you build. Start small, and buy as necessary.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the Express editions may already be sufficient.

Comment: sure can! Straight from the horse's mouth (see question #7):
http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/faq/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a look at the [Visual Studio Editions comparison sheet](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en) and just check what you need. Note that from a technical perspective, you are not locked if you choose to start with a smaller edition.

Answer (score 1):

At least Pro - given the description above you want to look at the [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/) programme. If you don't/can't go down that route then you should be looking at an MSDN sub to at least the VS Pro level.

Comment: What is in your opinion the reason not to use Standard? I'm not questioning your choice, I'd rather see why you would have at least Pro.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure any more - it was a combination of VS features and MSDN entitlements, now I'm revisting. There were some serious gaps in terms of proper project structure in the original express editions too. Hmm, looking at the comparison there's not a lot at the raw code level between pro and standard (in terms of Visual Studio at least) although there's quite a lot in terms of SDKs and the like (and those may be obtainable after the fact anyway). Server explorer is nice but not essential, never used remote debugging... Still leaves the MSDN question.

Comment: I think one of the Pro features that *may* be worth the larger edition is unit testing, which is part of Pro since the 2008 version. But other than that, It seems there's nothing important missing, since Standard has all the class designer tools and also has add-in support (which is a feature that is lacking in the Express editions). I used Remote Debugging a few times, though. Don't know how VMWare's Visual Studio add-in compares.

Comment: Keep in mind that Standard is going away with VS2010, so if you're considering future upgrade, it may be better to go with Professional now (it has a straightforward upgrade path). See http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/10/visual-studio-2010-simplified-to-four-skus-beta-2-arrives.ars.

Comment: @Pavel - that's a good point - if one were starting now it might as well be with 2010 unless there are compelling reasons to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the Express Editions and upgrade to another edition if you miss functionallity (e.g. Add-Ins like Resharper; they cannot be used in the express edition). Upgrading is no problem since you can use your projects in all editions.